# Why "error: invalid escape sequence?"

Tags: datetime, embedded-linux, glib, vala

According to the [valadoc](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime.format)

```
var now = new DateTime.now(new TimeZone.local());
var timestamp = now.format("\%F.\%T");
```

should set timestamp to "2012-08-28.09:51:06." Why "error: invalid escape sequence" on "F" and "T?" Other formats from the [valadoc](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime.format) cause the same error and now.to_string() is in fact "2012-08-28T09:51:06+0000"

Edit: Perhaps embedded-linux target is missing something?

Edit: The test code [here](http://fpaste.org/BQZ0/) prints "(null)" in this project which uses glib 2.26.1.

Comment: Just a semi-random guess, but have you tried `"\\%F.\\%T"` or `"%F.%T"`?

Comment: @NullUserException: Yes I did. Both clear the build error but return "" rather than the timestamp string at run-time.

Comment: Just FYI, there's a `new DateTime.now_local()`.

Comment: @nemequ: as I said, tried that and did not cause build error but does not return formatted date string, only "".

Comment: When I said "works", I meant it.  I get a properly formatted string not an empty string.  Test program at http://fpaste.org/BQZ0/ yields something like "2012-08-30.10:27:20".  AFAICT the g_date_time_format implementation doesn't rely on anything special from libc, so the results should be consistent.  Perhaps you're using an old version of glib with a bug?

Comment: @nemequ: Tried your test code on the target. I believe you but perhaps it is an issue with glib 2.26.1 as you suggest. `GLib.stdout.printf ("%s\n", timestamp)` prints `(null)` on the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As NullUserException mentioned, you shouldn't be including the backslashes--that is what is causing the invalid escape sequence error.

The reason it still doesn't work after removing the backslashes is that the %T format specifier wasn't added until the 2.30 cycle.  The relevant commit is [414c8ce532c19fe65deb8dfb80222d0164be5cbe](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/commit/?id=414c8ce532c19fe65deb8dfb80222d0164be5cbe)

You can work around it by doing something like this instead:

```
var timestamp = now.format ("%F.%H:%M:%S");
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thanks a million.